# ANY Crystal Reports working example with SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, crystal-reports

is there anybody with working Crystal Report and SQLite? any info would be great. SQLite is one of the fastest database in world but somehow there is no examples how to connect those two.

I don't need any rhetorical answers..i need real code..to get started with.

Or maybe you can tell me other solutions to replace CR with.

**EDIT:** For those who new to this like i'm. All you need to do is Add new dataset as in screenshot, create table with the same name that will be used in this report, add the same fields as will be used in report. Then with Database Expert add this dataset, add fields to report and they will appear :)

here is how i run in C# netikslumai1 is CrystalReportDocument, darbineLenta is my string variable with database name. DataSet1 is **COMPONENT** not that dataset we added like in screenshot.

```
            netikslumai1.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\netikslumai.rpt");

        netikslumai1.SetDataSource(dataSet1.Tables[darbineLenta]);

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = netikslumai1;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly locate your SQLite Database, from Database Expert in a crystal Report. To connect the SQLite and the Crystal Report, at first you need to create a system DSN to your database. For this

```
Control Panel 
--> Administrative Tools
--> Data Sources(ODBC)
--> System DSN
--> Create New by clicking Add 
--> Select SQLite ODBC Driver 
--> Give a custom name for DSN and 
--> Now browse and select your database.
```

In the Crystal Report you can find this DSN you have created in 
`Create New Connection 
 --> ODBC (RDO)
 --> Select the DSN`. If you locate the DSN then all the tables from your database will be automatically added to your crystal Report. Hope it will help you, Happy coding.

EDIT:

First add one dataset control to your project of type dataset1.xsd and fill all the values of the database to the dataset. Then by going through `Database Expert --> Project Data --> ADO .Net datasets` select and display in your report.

[image]

Comment: But my database files is automatically created in runtime, so can i assign it in runtime? SQlite is good because of mobility..

Comment: what do you mean by database files here? Is it the values of the database tables?

Comment: So if i do your method and it imports my fields.. but in custom machine there will be no DSN and there will be such file what i used in my development machine to asign DSN - this will work in customer's pc? i do not need to set DSN in customer machine? I want to have zero configuration solution, so no need to set up any stuff in customer pc.

Comment: @Tommix, well nice point. So, instead of doing like that you do which is in my edit.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "of type dataset1.xsd" this is export from DataSet.Tables["tablename"] yes? or what? cause in DataSet component i don't see any xsd... Sorry for dummy questions.. This is my first attempt with CR. Cause i have DataSet component in project but it's not shown in "ADO .Net datasets"

Comment: Don't even know how it works..i did not assign nothing to that new dataset..but it shows my data.. strange as hell..but thanks! :D

Comment: @Tommix, Refer to this to know how it works http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/Crystal_Report__90.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dataset object with the same fields you want to display in the report, use **exactly** the same field names. Design your report using this dataset object. Finally populate the report in the code using your SQLite db.

Comment: I'm using this:  `netikslumai1.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\netikslumai.rpt");
             netikslumai1.SetDataSource(dataSet1.Tables["darbineLenta"]);

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = netikslumai1;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();` AND I"M GETTING "The report has no tables" error.

Comment: The idea is using the dataset ONLY to design the report: place the fields, grouping, etc. in the design view of crystal reports. Then you use your database access layer to retrieve the information you want to display on it. If the fields name match, should be OK. I'll update the awnser with some code.

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate your help, but i think lower answer is kinda the same as you was suggesting so it worked for me..but i can't select both as good answer.. cause he was faster i selected him. But thank you too! i do not have enough points to even mark your answer as useful.

Comment: Yep, now it looks the same, no problem at all.